# Robolectric AndroidX fragments NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, robolectric, androidx, androidx-test

After migration of code and tests to **AndroidX**, all seems to work pretty well, however Robolectric junit tests for two fragments are failing due to **NoClassDefFoundError: androidx/fragment/testing/R$style** exception.
The stack trace:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: androidx/fragment/testing/R$style     at 
>   androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario$EmptyFragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentScenario.java:79)
>     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
>     at
>   androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:674)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.android.controller.ActivityController.lambda$create$0(ActivityController.java:69)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:365)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.android.controller.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:69)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.android.controller.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:74)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.android.internal.LocalActivityInvoker.startActivity(LocalActivityInvoker.java:39)
>     at
>   androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.launch(ActivityScenario.java:207)
>     at
>   androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario.internalLaunch(FragmentScenario.java:283)
>     at
>   androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario.launchInContainer(FragmentScenario.java:265)

For testing fragments I'm using FragmentScenario, and it seems the FragmentScenario.EmptyFragmentActivity refers to a missing R class from a package androidx.fragment.testing.R:

> setTheme(getIntent().getIntExtra(THEME_EXTRAS_BUNDLE_KEY,
>                      R.style.FragmentScenarioEmptyFragmentActivityTheme));

Any idea what might be wrong? Maybe I'm missing a dependency that's not that obvious to me.

Reproducible in following project:
https://github.com/marcinbak/androidx-test-error

Also reported in Google's issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122321150

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to answer from Google it is required to include *androidx_fragment_test* (*androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.1.0-alpha03*) artifact in the testing APK (not in instrumentation APK or testing dependency).

What this means it has to be added as **debugImplementation androix_fragment_test** in your build.gradle file.

If you also run tests on release target then you have to add **implementation androix_fragment_test**.

You can see the whole conversation in Google's issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122321150

Comment: If I put it as debugImplementation I get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.restoreUncaughtExceptionHandler()V`

Comment: I have the same problem to @m0skit0.

Comment: It may be related this issue. https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/5092
With Robolectric 4.2.1, it worked for me.

Comment: Worth noting that you have to use debugImplementation, you can't use testImplementation for this dependency

Comment: also worth noting `androidx.test:core` is a dependency of `androidx.fragment:fragment-testing` so implementation of that must be covered accordingly